# Matrix Multiplication: Memory Allocation Error

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, matrix-multiplication

When I run my program I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 16 byte(s) in 2 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7f5ab1fd8bc8 in malloc (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0x10dbc8)
    #1 0x55c072236541 in multiply ../../src/mexp/mexp.c:10
    #2 0x55c072238024 in main ../../src/mexp/mexp.c:101
    #3 0x7f5ab13930b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)

Direct leak of 8 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7f5ab1fd8bc8 in malloc (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0x10dbc8)
    #1 0x55c072236445 in multiply ../../src/mexp/mexp.c:8
    #2 0x55c072238024 in main ../../src/mexp/mexp.c:101
    #3 0x7f5ab13930b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)

Direct leak of 8 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7f5ab1fd8bc8 in malloc (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0x10dbc8)
    #1 0x55c0722374d3 in main ../../src/mexp/mexp.c:67
    #2 0x7f5ab13930b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 32 byte(s) leaked in 4 allocation(s).
```

I think the error might be caused by these lines:
Lines 7-10:

```
int **product = malloc(sizeof(int*) * n);
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
    product[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
int **temp = malloc(sizeof(int*) * n);
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
    temp[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
```

Line 67:

```
fscanf(fptr, "%d", &a[i][j]);
```

My code is for matrix exponentiation(matrix multiplying to itself). This is the source code:

```
void multiply(int *arr[], int n, int x){
    int **product = malloc(sizeof(int*) * n);
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) product[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    int **temp = malloc(sizeof(int*) * n);
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) temp[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
            
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
            temp[i][j] = arr[i][j];
        }
    }

    //keep multiplying until n
    int count = 1;
    while(count<x){
        //multiply the matrix
        int sum = 0;
        for (int r=0; r<n; r++){
            for (int c=0; c<n; c++){
                sum = 0;
                for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
                    sum+=arr[r][i]*temp[i][c];
                }
                product[r][c] = sum;
            }   
        }
        
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
                arr[i][j] = product[i][j];
            }
        }
        count++;
    }
    
    for (int r=0; r<n; r++){
        for (int c=0; c<n; c++){
            printf("%d ",product[r][c]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    free(product);
    free(temp);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    FILE *fptr = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    if(fptr == NULL){
    
    }else{
        //get dimensions
        int n;
        fscanf(fptr, "%d", &n);
        printf("%d\n", n);
        
        //create matrix
        int **a = malloc(sizeof(int*) * n);
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++) a[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
        for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<n; j++){
                fscanf(fptr, "%d", &a[i][j]);
            }
        }
        
        //get exponent
        int x;
        fscanf(fptr, "%d", &x);
        printf("%d\n", x);
        
        //calculate
        if(x==0){
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
                for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
                    if(i == j){
                        a[i][j] = 1;
                    }else{
                        a[i][j] = 0;
                    }
                
                    printf("%d", a[i][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
        }else if(x==1){
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
                for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
                    printf("%d", a[i][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
        }else{
            multiply(a,n,x);
        }        
        
        
        //free
        free(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have not freed the pointers in the array. You freed this one `product = malloc(sizeof(int*) * n);` but not these ones `product[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);`. Like the allocation loop write a loop that calls `free(product[i])`. Same for `temp`.

Comment: The definition of a memory leak is allocating something without freeing it. Every call to `malloc()` should have a corresponding call to `free()`.